# Verify polynomial equation for set of 3D data

Tags: fitting, interpolation, polynomials, data

Goodmorning,

I mean to this link:
[Find polynomial equation for set of 3D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48911/find-polynomial-equation-for-set-of-3d-data/174511#174511)

I tried to verify the result, namely if the interpolation is correct, but I found something that I don't understand.

I rewrite the code used:

```
points = {{144, 18, 52}, {142, 24, 40}, {124, 12, 40}, {64, 30, 48}, {96, 30, 
32}, {74, 26, 56}, {136, 26, 24}, {54, 22, 64}, {92, 22, 16}, {96, 14, 
64}, {92, 10, 56}, {82, 10, 24}, {76, 6, 48}, {68, 6, 32}};

fit == ((lmf = 
     LinearModelFit[
      RotateRight /@ points, {x, z, x^2, z^2, x*z}, {x, z}]) // 
   Normal)
```

I don't find the correct solution. I done this to evaluate the results, I took from the first element {144, 18, 52}:

```
x0 = 144;
z0 = 52;

lmf[x0, z0]
```

and I get this:

```
62.0327
```

I expected this: y = 18

Help, please! Thank you!

Comment: `RotateRight /@ points` puts your coordinates in the order `{z, x, y}`, not `{x, z, y}`.  Either adjust your usage or use `points[[All, {1, 3, 2}]]`.  Then `lmf[x0, z0]` will be `15.27`.  You shouldn't expect to get `18`, since you cannot interpolate so many points with such a model.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ok, thank you, but there is a method to well interpolate these many points?

Answer (score 3):

`Interpolation` will interpolate, if the points are well-poised:

```
if = Interpolation[points[[All, {1, 3, 2}]], InterpolationOrder -> All];
Show[
 Plot3D[if[x, z], {x, z} ∈ ConvexHullMesh@points[[All, {1, 3}]], PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, Sphere /@ points[[All, {1, 3, 2}]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Now, how to get the mathematical function? I tried to use {Normal[if]} 'code'
, but no answer. Thank you to all.

Comment: I tried to adapt the points by increasing the order of the interpolation function, following @HenrikSchumacher 's example.
But, there is an automatic method?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the last code don't work for me. I get this: [code] InterpolatingPolynomial::ipab: Abscissa specification 144 in {144,52,18} is not a point in 2 dimensions. >>

Comment: @user8011311 Maybe `InterpolatingPolynomial[{#[[{1, 3}]], #[[2]]} & /@ points, {x, z}]`? I'm not on *M* at the moment and I forgot the syntax was different.

Comment: ok, this give me a results, but in fraction format, and for see in the number coefficients?

Comment: @user8011311 Look up the functions `N`, `Expand`, `Simplify`.  I think one of them will give what you're after.

Comment: ok, I used  {Expand[N[u]]} with {u} it's your formula.

Comment: but, now there is a problem, I change the data in {points} and I get this: [code] InterpolatingPolynomial::poised: The interpolation points ... are not poised, so an interpolating polynomial of total degree 7 \
could not be found. >>

Comment: @user8011311 Yes, hence the hypothesis in my answer.  The first section of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.2700&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives a brief overview.  Non-poised means that the (Vandermonde) coefficient matrix is singular.  This property is a function of the points (in the xz domain) and the interpolation space, e.g. polynomials of total degree at most 7.  You can expand the space (go up to a higher degree) and apply Henrik's approach.  I'm not sure it's known how far you have to increase the degree to get a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have 14 points, hence 14 equations, so you also need at least 14 parameters for an exact fit. If you really want to have an exact fit, you have to include more variables into your model. For example, you could use all polynomials of order 4 or less:

```
points = {{144, 18, 52}, {142, 24, 40}, {124, 12, 40}, {64, 30, 
    48}, {96, 30, 32}, {74, 26, 56}, {136, 26, 24}, {54, 22, 64}, {92,
     22, 16}, {96, 14, 64}, {92, 10, 56}, {82, 10, 24}, {76, 6, 
    48}, {68, 6, 32}};
pts = points[[All, {1, 3, 2}]];
model = Rest[Flatten[Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4 - i}]]];
lmf = LinearModelFit[
   pts,
   Flatten[Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4 - i}]],
   {x, y}
   ];
fit = Normal[lmf]
Show[
 Graphics3D[Sphere[#, 2] & /@ pts],
 Plot3D[
  fit, {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]]}, {y, 
   Sequence @@ MinMax[pts[[All, 2]]]}
  ],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

But note that this model has more than 14 parameters, so there are multiple solutions! (And Mathematica tells you so via a warning message.)

If the points are statistical data, it is really bad practice to use that many parameters (it leads to [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)).